# Define department hierarchy using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchy

Given the following structure:

```
data1 = {
        'emp': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        'dep': [100, 500, 200, 100, 200, 300, 400, 300, 200],
        'boss': [6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, None, 7, 6]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['emp', 'dep', 'boss'])
```

The data is coming from a flat CSV file.
Now I have to establish a hierarchy between the departments.
Rules are the following:

- Every employee works in a department
- The employees might have a boss (the CEO has no boss)
- The department where the boss is working is the parent department of the given employee
- The upper level department has no parent

The expected result would be like this:

```
   dep  parent  boss
0  100   300.0     6
1  500   400.0     7
2  200   300.0     6
3  300   400.0     7
4  400     NaN     7
```

Is there any pandas trick to solve this?
I can so that in an iterative way by reading the CSV file and using dicts, but my goal would be solving that with pandas.
Any idea?

**Edit:**
There was a mistake in the sample data. Emp 8 has of course the same boss as emp 6.

Comment: try : **df1.merge(df1, left_on='boss', right_on='emp', how='left')[['dep_x', 'dep_y', 'boss_x']]**
but I don't understand how do you know that dep 400 boss is 7 and why emp 6 and emp 8 have diffent bosses

Comment: First of all, the solution is right if you put .drop_duplicates() at the end to get a distinct department list. My mistake: emp 8 has the same boss as emp. :-) 6. You are right, it was not clear enough. A boss must be a manager. And if a manager has no manager, than he is the big boss. So emp 7 is his own boss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge df1 with itself to find the departement of the current boss, then only keep the relevant columns and drop the duplicates. For it to work, the boss column must be filled with the emp column to finally have the boss of the higher level department.

In Pandas, it could be:

```
df2 = df1[['boss', 'dep']].assign(boss=df1['boss'].combine_first(
    df1['emp'])).merge(df1[['emp', 'dep']].rename(
    columns={'dep': 'parent'}), how='left', left_on='boss', right_on='emp'
)[['dep', 'parent', 'boss']].drop_duplicates().astype('int')
def2.loc[df2['parent'] == df2['dep'], 'parent'] = np.nan   # a dep cannot be its parent
```

which gives as expected:

```
   dep  parent  boss
0  100   300.0     6
1  500   400.0     7
2  200   300.0     6
5  300   400.0     7
6  400     NaN     7
```

Comment: But dep 400 has no parent. That is the highest level (CEO). Therefore it's parent should be NaN (and of course the boss of the CEO department is the CEO himself, so that is correct